# How to use a loop to request a URL, scrape data, grab a new URL from that page and move on to the next page X times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cheerio

I am looking to:

1. Open a known URL `(www.source.com/1 below)`
2. scrape all URLs on that page `(e.g. www.urllookingfor.com/1 to .../10)` and log to console
3. scrape a new URL `(e.g. www.source.com/2)` from that page
4. load the next page and repeat the process X number of times

Imagine a list of 50 URLs dividend across 5 pages where you need to click the `next` button to move on a page.

The first two steps work fine, but I think the issue is that the `nextLink` isn't updated before the loop runs again. Essentially what happens is that step four gets repeated with the original URL and not the 'new' URL. The steps above are within an if loop.

I've tried using `setTimeout`, `async`...`await` as I think the issue is that it doesn't have time to load the 'new' URL before the next function is complete but this did not work.

If I add `console.log(URL)` within the if function, it will print the original URL. But when I add `console.log` to outside the if loop it prints the updated URL which makes me think 'nextLink' isn't updated until after the if loop.

I've also tried repeating the functions over and over (essentially a repeated if statement), but this also does not seem to update 'nextLink' before the next function runs which goes against the above.

```
let nextLink = www.source.com/1

//this pulls source page and scrapes required URLs
const getDatafromPage = () => {
    request(nextLink, (error, response, html) => {
        if((!error) && (response.statusCode == 200)) 
        {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('.class1').each((i, el) => {
                let link = $(el).find('.class2').attr('href');
                console.log(`${link});
            })
        }
    })
}

//this gets the next URL
const getNextLink = () => {
    request(nextLink, (error, response, html) => {
        if((!error) && (response.statusCode == 200)) 
        {        
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            nextLink = $('.class3').attr('href');
        }
    })
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    getDatafromPage();

    getNextLink();
}

console.log(nextLink)
```

Expected results (all 50 URLs from the pages and ends by logging the last source URL)

```
 www.urllookingfor.com/1
 ...
 www.urllookingfor.com/50
 www.source.com/5
```

Actual results (repeats the first page, but then logs the next page at the end):

```
 www.urllookingfor.com/1
 ...
 www.urllookingfor.com/10
 www.urllookingfor.com/1
 ...
 www.urllookingfor.com/10
 www.source.com/2
```

Comment: looks like a use case for RxJS (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs)

Answer (score 0):

Here's more or less what it might look like when I do it:

```
const doPage = async ($) => {
  // do stuff here
}

;(async function(){
  let response = await request(url)
  let $ = cheerio.load(response)
  await doPage($)
  let a
  // keep following next links
  while(a = $('[rel=next]')[0]){
    url = new URL($(a).attr('href'), url).href 
    response = await request(url)
    $ = cheerio.load(response)
    await doPage($)
  }
})()
```